# Eligibility trace algorithm, the update order

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, sarsa, monte-carlo-tree-search

I am reading [Silver et al (2012) "Temporal-Difference Search in Computer Go"](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Publications_files/tdsearch.pdf), and trying to understand the update order for the eligibility trace algorithm.
In the Algorithm 1 and 2 of the paper, weights are updated before updating the eligibility trace.  I wonder if this order is correct (Line 11 and 12 in the Algorithm 1, and Line 12 and 13 of the Algorithm 2).
Thinking about an extreme case with `lambda=0`, the parameter is not updated with the initial state-action pair (since `e` is still 0). So I doubt the order possibly should be the opposite.

Can someone clarify the point?

I find the paper very instructive for learning the reinforcement learning area, so would like to understand the paper in detail.

If there is a more suitable platform to ask this question, please kindly let me know as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For future reference; questions like this are probably a better fit over on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ rather than StackOverflow. We also have support for proper math in questions/answers there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're correct, `e` should be updated **before** `theta`. That's also what should happen according to the math in the paper. See, for example, Equations (7) and (8), where `e_t` is first computed using `phi(s_t)`, and only THEN is `theta` updated using `delta V_t` (which would be `delta Q` in the control case).

Note that what you wrote about the extreme case with `lambda=0` is not entirely correct. The initial state-action pair will still be involved in an update (not in the first iteration, but they will be incorporated in `e` during the second iteration). However, it looks to me like the very first reward `r` will never be used in any updates (because it only appears in the very first iteration, where `e` is still `0`). Since this paper is about Go, I suspect it will not matter though; unless they're doing something unconventional, they probably only use non-zero rewards for the terminal game state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as well as the suggestion of the https://ai.stackexchange.com/.  Your point about my case also makes sense.